# Wix Setup Editor Root Element Missing

Tags: wix3.11

Using wix setup editor / Wix toolset latest build and Wax.

I managed to create my setup project just fine on Friday. However, going back to it today and trying to load the setup editor I am met with this message.

I have tried to navigate to the file path it shows however, such a file does not exist.

I have tried reinstalling all three components to no avail.

Quite stumped here, does anybody know why this would suddenly happen upon re-opening VS a few days later?

[image]